# Uninstallable Dependencies while Installing package "purple-facebook"

Tags: package-management, software-installation, lubuntu, dependencies, libpurple

Following the steps listed [here](https://jgeboski.github.io/#package-repositories)

Among other things, the package "facebook-purple" itself doesn't show up in synaptic and cannot be found by terminal; I have updated my package lists and so forth, and when looking around in synaptic, I DID find the package "purple-facebook:amd64" and then tried to install it via terminal, I got the following output

```
purple-facebook:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.14) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.37.3) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 0.14) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libpurple0:amd64 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not installable
```

I have the "non-amd64" version of all of these installed up to the current version; I'm assuming the issue is my package management only grabbing the amd64 version of "purple-facebook"

For kicks, I tried installing the package through synaptic, and got this (slightly different) output

```
purple-facebook:amd64:
Depends: libc6 (>=2.14) but it is not installable
Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>=2.37.3) but it is not installable
Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0 (>=0.14) but it is not installable
Depends: libpurple0 (>=2.8.0) but it is not installable
```

For reference, I'm just coming back to ubuntu after a couple of years back in Windows Hell, running lubuntu 17.10 on a Dell Inspiron 1545 Notebook
Any thoughts?

Comment: What does this report? `dpkg --print-architecture && dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: i386

I was under the impression I'd installed the 64-bit lubuntu distro but I may be incorrect; I *am* running a 64-bit processor.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that this is going to continue to cause me problems forever, as various software sources will autodetect my processor and spit 64 bit versions at me without asking.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that you installed wrong-version or non-Ubuntu software source(s) and that they are causing causing version conflicts.

Comment: I don't *think* I did, but for safety, how would I check?

Comment: You would edit your question to include the contents of all files in /etc/apt/sources*. There may be several.

Comment: Well you could do a re-install & use the amd64 image or maybe try this, see if it improves your situation, `sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64`

Comment: So upon some further research, I have a 64 bit processor but only a 32 bit bus, so I need to run the 32bit OS. The issue, then, is that my package manager, with the correct repository added (I triple checked) is only seeing the 64 bit version of the software.